# Axios chunk requests for reverse geocoding with Google Maps API

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api-3, axios

pls help! I'm trying to do a batch reverse-geocoding operation using nodejs, axios and google maps api. This is the main function:

```
function reverse_geocode (data) {
  console.log('Working...')
  let records = []

  chunks = chunkArray(data, 50) // Split data into chunks

  chunks.forEach(chunk => {

    records.push(process_chunk(chunk)) // Do the requests for each chunk then
                                      // push into array the results

  })
  console.log(records)
}
```

I have a set of 773 {lat, lng} objects which I split in chunks of 50 elements using this function:

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
  var index = 0
  var arrayLength = myArray.length
  var tempArray = []

  for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
      myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size)
      tempArray.push(myChunk)
  }

  return tempArray
}
```

Next, I pass each chunk to an async function that makes the requests using axios.all:

```
async function process_chunk(chunk){
  const key = process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY
  let promises = []
  let chunk_records = []
  chunk.forEach(element => {
    query = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?`+
          `latlng=${element.latitude},${element.longitude}&key=${key}`+
          `&result_type=administrative_area_level_3`

    promises.push(axios.get(query)
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
    }))
  })

  let responses = await axios.all(promises)
                              .catch(function(err){
                                console.log(err)
                              })

  console.log('Responses downloaded... Processing')

  responses.forEach(function(response){
    res_data = response.data['results'][0]

    comune = res_data['address_components'][0]['long_name']
    provincia = res_data['address_components'][1]['short_name']
    lat = res_data['geometry']['location']['lat']
    lng = res_data['geometry']['location']['lng']

    chunk_records.push(
      {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng,
        comune: comune,
        provincia: provincia
      }
    )
  })
  return chunk_records
}
```

The final result is records having pending promises and after a few seconds several 'socket hang up' errors with code 'ECONNRESET':

```
Listening
Working...
[
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }
]
Error: socket hang up
    at connResetException (internal/errors.js:570:14)       
    at TLSSocket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:440:23)       
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
```

What I'm doing wrong? Are there other ways to do the same things? Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it out by myself. Pretty stupid mistake actually. So in forEach in `reverse_geocode()` I don't wait for the promise returned by `process_chunk()` to resolve.
Switched to normal for loop:

```
async function reverse_geocode (data) {
  console.log('Working...')
  let records = []

  chunks = chunkArray(data, 50) // Split data into chunks

  for(let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++){
    processed_chunk = await process_chunk(chunks[i])
    records.push(processed_chunk)
  }
  console.log(records)
}
```